# winForm reload not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a full screen user login window application in C#,On form_load it gets data from database and shows in the form. when there any db exception or server unavailable rise i have shown a retry button and a error message. when user clicks the retry button the form load event is called again  like

```
private void btnRetry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1_Load(sender, e);
        }
```

But sometimes the load event is not properly called ie half of the data is only loading resting of the data will not be shown but all the data is getting from the database at those time no exception is also occurring

**But this is not happening always,its occurring some rare times**

i have tried

```
private void btnRetry_Click(object send, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }
```

then also same result ,then i tired to provide a 5sec delay there is no change.

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); // 5 seconds delay
```

My aim is to load the form again with data from  the database(if available) when user clicks the retry button.Please help..

Comment: Can you call the load as `Form1_Load(this, EventArgs.Empty);`

Comment: There is no such thing as this: **"asp.net window application"** You're either using ASP.NET, or you're using WinForms. Which is it?

Comment: i tried it but same result...:(

Comment: @Code Gray: it would be a WinForms application as he uses `Form1_Load`. In asp.net it would be `Page_Load`, normally.

Comment: @UwConcept: You can call it anything you want using either technology. I wasn't calling for you to speculate, I was hoping the asker would clarify what he was asking. And that happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally Extract the loading of the database and other functionality to a separate method i.e. `LoadForm();` and call that function from the `Form_Load` method.

Doing so, you can call `LoadForm();` from anywhere in the code, which would result in reloading all the data needed.

```
Form1_Load()
{
    LoadForm();
}

ButtonReload_Click()
{
    LoadForm();
}
```

*The code provided is not syntax correct and serves only as clarification*